# How to get current logging formatter?

Tags: python, logging

I'm using the logging module from the python standard library and would like to obtain the current `Formatter`. The reason is that I'm using `multiprocessing` module and for each process I'd like to assign its logger another file handler to log to its own log file. When I do this in the following way

```py
logger = logging.getLogger('subprocess')
log_path = 'log.txt'
with open(log_path, 'a') as outfile:
        handler = logging.StreamHandler(outfile)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
```

the messages in `log.txt` have no formatting at all, but I would like the message to be in the same format as my typical logging format. My typical logging setup is shown below

```py
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(name)s - %(process)d | %(message)s',
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
        level=os.environ.get('LOGLEVEL', 'INFO').upper(),
    )
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Since it looks like the `Formatter` object is associated with the `Handler` object, I tried to obtain handler from the main `Logger` object which has the correct formatting. So I called

```py
logger.handlers
```

but I got an empty list `[]`.

So my question is, where do I get the `Formatter` object which has the same format that my main logger has?

For the record, I'm using python 3.8 on macOS but the code will be deployed to Linux (but still python 3.8).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the `cpython` source code on `logging.basicConfig`, it appears that the formatter object which contains your formatting string is eventually added to a handler that is passed to the root logger (see: [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4ac923f2756f835f512339ee181348cc535ab07f/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L2038) ). So you can obtain the handler (and therefore the formatter) from the root logger object by doing

```py
logging.root.handlers[0].formatter
```

In particular, to achieve the subprocess logging handler in the question, you can do this instead

```py
        handler = logging.StreamHandler(outfile)
        handler.setFormatter(logging.root.handlers[0].formatter)
        handler.setLevel(logging.root.level)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
```

which will set your handler to the same logging format (and level as well!) as that of your usual logger object.

Comment: key for me was running `logging.basicConfig()` first. before that, `logging.root.handlers` is an empty list. and the format string itself, (which is what I wanted) is `logging.root.handlers[0].formatter._fmt`